# Writing a simple syntax parser

Tags: php, regex, recursion, syntax

Here's what I'd like to do - in Php: given a string, have a result like this:

- `(a()?b|c)` a is a function that returns true of false. This should give `b` or `c` after calling `a()`
- `(a()?(b()?d|e)|c)`. Same principle. The final result should be `d`, `e` or `c`
- `(a()?(b()?d|e)|(c()?f|g))`. Same principle. The final result should be `d`, `e`, `f` or `g`

The problem I'm facing is that `a` (in my previous examples) can be an expression too, like this:

```
((h() ? a | i) ? (b() ? d | e) | (c() ? f | g))
```

I'm trying to use a regexp, to do it but this doesn't work.

```
$res=preg_match_all('/\([^.\(]+\)/', $str, $matches);
```

So in the end I would like do call my function like this:

```
$final_string=compute("(a(x(y(z()?o|p)))?(b()?d|e)|(c()?f|g))");
```

The final result in `$final_string` should be `d`, `e`, `f` or `g`

I'm pretty sure something has been done before but cant find it on google.
How would you do?

To be more precise, here's how I'd like to have the string to be analyzed:

```
$str =
    "
    (myfunction(12684444)
    ?   {* comment *}
        (
            myfunction(1)|
            myfunction(2)|
            myfunction(80)|
            myfunction(120)|
            myfunction(184)|
            myfunction(196)
        ?   {* comment *}
            AAAAA
            {* /comment *}
        |
            {* Ignore all other values: *}
            BBBBB
        ) {* /comment *}

    |   {* comment *}
        CCCC
    )";
```

Comment: did you mean this https://regex101.com/r/pG0uG1/4 ?

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion, but I mean that but with an infinite number of recursion, not with hard-coded solution that just applies to my question.

Comment: Do you just need a recursive pattern to parse the balanced parenths?

Comment: @sln Yes but it's not that simple (for me anyway...).

Comment: Leave regexpes at all. Write your own small parser/lexer, it's simpler.

Comment: For those reading this, I've learned Python since then, re-wrote it in Python, and it has been faster to write, faster to re-read, thus understand, and I've finally been able to finish it! (It was too complex with Php (too many lines, debugging too archaic with xdebug..)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my "basic" version that works and does the job. It's "half" recursive (a loop that may call the function or not) and the improvements I'm planning to do (handle "`+`" separator to "add" returns of two functions, and handle "`=`" to set variables to make short aliases of the value of a return function) seem quite easy to implement in the `_compute()` function... maybe because I wrote the code myself, and maybe because, like Paul Crovella said, I'm not using PCRE, because it can very easily become an unmaintainable mess...

NB: this code can be easily optimized, and it's not perfect (there are some cases it doesnt work like `(a()+b())`)... but if someone is willing to finish it he/she's welcome!

```
class Parser
{
    private $ref = array(
        'a'         => array( 'type' => 'fn',  'val' => '_a'),
        'b'         => array( 'type' => 'fn',  'val' => '_b'),
        'c'         => array( 'type' => 'fn',  'val' => '_c'),
        'd'         => array( 'type' => 'fn',  'val' => '_d'),
        'e'         => array( 'type' => 'fn',  'val' => '_e'),
        'f'         => array( 'type' => 'fn',  'val' => '_f'),
        'intro'         => array( 'type' => 'fn',  'val' => '_getIntro'),
        'insist'        => array( 'type' => 'fn',  'val' => '_insist'),
        'summoner_name' => array( 'type' => 'fn',  'val' => '_getSummonerName'),
        'type'          => array( 'type' => 'fn',  'val' => '_getEtat'),
        ' '             => array( 'type' => 'str', 'val' => ' ')
    );
    private function _a($p)        { return 'valfnA'; }
    private function _b($p)        { return 'valfnB'; }
    private function _c($p)        { return 'valfnC'; }
    private function _d($p)        { return 'valfnD'; }
    private function _e($p)        { return 'valfnE'; }
    private function _f($p)        { return 'valfnF'; }
    private function _getIntro($p)        { return 'valGetIntro'; }
    private function _insist($p)          { return 'valInsist'; }
    private function _getSummonerName($p) { return 'valGetSqmmonerName'; }
    private function _getEtat($p)         { return 'valGetEtat'; }

    private function _convertKey($key, $params=false)
    {
        $retour = 'indéfini';
        if (isset($this->ref[$key])) {
            $val = $this->ref[$key];
            switch ($val['type']) {
                case 'fn':
                    $val=$val['val'];
                    if (method_exists($this, $val)) {
                        $retour = $this->$val($params);
                    }
                    break;

                default:
                    if (isset($this->val['val'])) {
                        $retour = $this->val['val'];
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
        return $retour;
    }
    private function _compute($str)
    {
        $p=strpos($str, '?');
        if ($p===false) {
            $p=strpos($str, '=');
            if ($p===false) {
                return $str;
            }
        } else {
            $or=strpos($str, '|');
            if ($or===false) {
                return false;
            }
            $s=substr($str,0,$p);
            if (empty($s) || (strtolower($s)=='false')) {
                return substr($str, $or+1);
            }
            return substr($str, $p+1, ($or-$p)-1);
        }
        return $str;
    }
    private function _getTexte($str, $i, $level)
    {
        if (empty($str)) {
            return $str;
        }
        $level++;
        $f   = (strlen($str)-$i);
        $val = substr($str, $i);
        do {
            $d = $i;
            do {
                $p=$d;
                $d=strpos($str, '(', $p+1);
                if (($p==$i) && ($d===false)) {
                    $retour = $this->_compute($str);
                    return $retour;
                } elseif (($d===false) && ($p>$i)) {
                    $f=strpos($str, ')', $p+1);
                    if ($f===false) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    $d=$p;
                    while((--$d)>=$i) {
                        if (($str[$d]!=' ')
                            && ($str[$d]!='_')
                            && (!ctype_alnum($str[$d]))
                        ) {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if ($d>=$i) {
                        $d++;
                    } else {
                        $d=$i;
                    }
                    $val=substr($str, $d, ($f-$d)+1);
                    $fn=substr($str, $d, $p-$d);
                    $param=$this->_getTexte(
                        substr($str, $p+1, ($f-$p)-1), 0, $level+1
                    );
                    if (!empty($fn)) {
                        $val = $this->_convertKey($fn, $param);
                    } else {
                        $val = $this->_compute($param);
                    }
                    $str = substr($str, 0, $d).$val.substr($str, $f+1);
                    break;
                } elseif ($d===false) {
                    break;
                }
            } while (true);
        } while (true);
    }
    public function parse($str)
    {
        $retour=preg_replace('/{\*[^.{]+\*}/', '', $str); //}
        $retour=str_replace("\n", "", $retour);
        $retour=str_replace("\r", "", $retour);
        while (strpos($retour, '  ')!==false) {
            $retour=str_replace("  ", " ", $retour);
        }
        return trim($this->_getTexte($retour, 0, 0));
    }
}

$p=new Parser();
$tests = [
    "a",
    "a()",
    "a(b)",
    "(a?b|c)",
    "(a()?(b()?d|e)|(c()?f|g))",
    "(a()?(b()?d|e)|(c()?f()|g))",
    "((h() ? a | i) ? (b() ? d | e) | (c() ? f | g))",
    "(a(d(f))?b(e(f))|c)",
    '(intro(intro(type(insist(poou))))?toutou|tutu)',
    'type()intro(intro(type(insist(poou))))?type()|tutu'
];
foreach ($tests as $test) {
    $res=$p->parse($test);
    echo $test.' = '.var_export($res,true)."\n";
}
```

Comment: it doesn't work yet with `(a()?(b()?d|e)|(c()?f|g))` but I'm on it I'll post the final version when it works ^^

Answer (score 4):

I believe you're looking for something like this. Explanatory comments interspersed along the way.

If you're going to extend the grammar much beyond what you've got (really even if you're not) write a proper parser rather than try to do everything in a single regex. This has been a fun exercise and shows some of the power of PCRE, but it can *very* easily become an unmaintainable mess.

---

#### Test Strings:

```
$tests = [
    "a",
    "a()",
    "a(b)",
    "(a?b|c)",
    "(a()?(b()?d|e)|(c()?f|g))",
    "((h() ? a | i) ? (b() ? d | e) | (c() ? f | g))",
    "(a(d(f))?b(e(f))|c)"
];
```

For use later.

---

#### Regex:

```
$regex = <<<'REGEX'
/
(?(DEFINE)
    # An expression is any function, ternary, or string.
    (?<expression>
        (?&function) | (?&ternary) | (?&string)
    )
)

^(?<expr>

    # A function is a function name (consisting of one or more word characters)
    # followed by an opening parenthesis, an optional parameter (expression),
    # and a closing parenthesis.
    # Optional space is allowed around the parentheses.
    (?<function>
        (?<func_name> \w+ )
        \s*\(\s*
        (?<parameter> (?&expression)? )
        \s*\)\s*
    )

    |

    # A ternary is an opening parenthesis followed by an 'if' expression,
    # a question mark, an expression evaluated when the 'if' is true,
    # a pipe, an expression evaluated when the 'if' is false, and a closing
    # parenthesis.
    # Whitespace is allowed after '('; surrounding '?' and '|'; and before ')'.
    (?<ternary>
        \(\s*
        (?<if> (?&expression) )
        \s*\?\s*
        (?<true> (?&expression) )
        \s*\|\s*
        (?<false> (?&expression) )
        \s*\)
    )

    |

    # A string, for simplicity's sake here, we'll call a sequence of word
    # characters.
    (?<string> \w+ )
)$
/x
REGEX;
```

Liberal use of named capturing groups helps a lot, as does the `x` (PCRE_EXTENDED) modifier to allow comments and whitespace. The `(?(DEFINE)...)` block lets you to define subpatterns for use by reference only.

---

#### Regex Demo:

```
foreach ($tests as $test) {
    if (preg_match($regex, $test, $m)) {
        echo "expression: $m[expr]\n";

        if ($m['function']) {
            echo "function: $m[function]\n",
                 "function name: $m[func_name]\n",
                 "parameter: $m[parameter]\n";
        } elseif ($m['ternary']) {
            echo "ternary: $m[ternary]\n",
                 "if: $m[if]\n",
                 "true: $m[true]\n",
                 "false: $m[false]\n";
        } else {
            echo "string: $m[string]\n";
        }

        echo "\n";
    }
}
```

#### Output:

```
expression: a
string: a

expression: a()
function: a()
function name: a
parameter: 

expression: a(b)
function: a(b)
function name: a
parameter: b

expression: (a?b|c)
ternary: (a?b|c)
if: a
true: b
false: c

expression: (a()?(b()?d|e)|(c()?f|g))
ternary: (a()?(b()?d|e)|(c()?f|g))
if: a()
true: (b()?d|e)
false: (c()?f|g)

expression: ((h() ? a | i) ? (b() ? d | e) | (c() ? f | g))
ternary: ((h() ? a | i) ? (b() ? d | e) | (c() ? f | g))
if: (h() ? a | i)
true: (b() ? d | e)
false: (c() ? f | g)

expression: (a(d(f))?b(e(f))|c)
ternary: (a(d(f))?b(e(f))|c)
if: a(d(f))
true: b(e(f))
false: c
```

A little verbose, but demonstrates well enough what's matching.

---

#### Example `compute()` Function:

```
function compute($expr) {
    $regex = '/.../x'; // regex from above
    if (!preg_match($regex, $expr, $m)) {
        return false;
    }

    if ($m['function']) {
        if ($m['parameter']) {
            return $m['func_name'](compute($m['parameter']));
        } else {
            return $m['func_name']();
        }
    }

    if ($m['ternary']) {
        return compute($m['if']) ? compute($m['true']) : compute($m['false']);
    }

    return $m['string'];
}
```

Pretty straight-forward - execute matched functions, evaluate matched ternary expressions, or return matched strings; recursing where appropriate.

---

#### `compute()` demo:

```
function a() {return true;}
function b() {return false;}
function d() {return true;}
function e() {return false;}
function h() {return true;}

foreach ($tests as $test) {
    $result = compute($test);
    echo "$test returns: ";
    var_dump($result);
}
```

#### Output:

```
a returns: string(1) "a"
a() returns: bool(true)
a(b) returns: bool(true)
(a?b|c) returns: string(1) "b"
(a()?(b()?d|e)|(c()?f|g)) returns: string(1) "e"
((h() ? a | i) ? (b() ? d | e) | (c() ? f | g)) returns: string(1) "e"
(a(d(f))?b(e(f))|c) returns: bool(false)
```

I'm pretty sure this is correct.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but there's only one thing missing: if you look at my latest example in my question - the complex string. each letter may be a function with a parameter, thus, instead of having `"(a?b|c)"` we might have something like `"(a(d)?b(e)|c)"` - with `d` and `e` that could possibly be functions too like `"(a(d(f))?b(e(f))|c)"`

Comment: You're right, I didn't express myself properly, I'm sorry. The principle is: if there's no parenthesis, it's not a function, dont try to call a function, let it like it is. So `(a?b(d)|c)` would be treated like this: `a` has no parenthesis so it's not a function to be called, so it's a "pure" string. This is in first place for evalution. So it's considered a "non null string" so it's true. Thus `b(d)` would always be called in this case, never `c` (which is not a function here too). Then `b(d)` would be called: function `b` with string `d` as a parameter.

Comment: I've modified my question and the samples. Thank you very much.

Comment: This is just perfect, thank you. Meanwhile I've almost finished my version without regexp, and I'll post it here just to have to different versions. Mine is less clear so I will probably end up using yours. Thank you very much again!

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on @PaulCrovella regex here a bit.
This will allow any level off nested parenthesis around any expression and be parsed
and trimmed accordingly. Whitespace is also trimmed.

PHP Sample:

```
 $rx = 
 '/
      ^ 
      (?<found>                     # (1 start)
           \h* 
           (?:

                # A function is a function name (consisting of one or more word characters)
                # followed by an opening parenthesis, an optional parameter (expression),
                # and a closing parenthesis.

                (?<function>                  # (2 start)
                     (?>
                          (?<func_name> \w+ )           # (3)
                          \h* \(   
                          (?<parameter>                 # (4 start)
                               (?&expression) 
                            |  
                          )                             # (4 end)
                          \h* \)  
                     )
                )                             # (2 end)

             |  

                # A ternary is an opening \'if\' expression,
                # a question mark, an expression evaluated when the \'if\' is true,
                # a pipe, an expression evaluated when the \'if\' is false.

                (?<pt> \( )?                  # (5)
                (?<ternary>                   # (6 start)
                     (?>
                          (?<if>                        # (7 start)
                               (?&expression)  
                          )                             # (7 end)
                          \h* \? \h*              
                          (?<true>                      # (8 start)
                               (?&expression)  
                          )                             # (8 end)
                          \h* \| \h*        
                          (?<false>                     # (9 start)
                               (?&expression)  
                          )                             # (9 end)
                     )
                )                             # (6 end)
                (?(\'pt\') \h* \) )

             |  

                # A string, for simplicity\'s sake here, we\'ll call a sequence of word
                # characters.

                (?<string>                    # (10 start)
                     (?> \w+ )
                )                             # (10 end)
             |  
                (?<parens>                    # (11 start)
                     (?>
                          \( \h* 
                          (?<parens_core>               # (12 start)
                               \h* 
                               (?&p_expression) 
                          )                             # (12 end)
                          \h* \)
                     )
                )                             # (11 end)
           )
      )                             # (1 end)
      \h* 
      $ 

      (?(DEFINE)
           # expression is any function, parenthesized-ternary, or string.
           (?<expression>                # (13 start)
                \h* 
                (?:
                     (?&function)  
                  |  \( (?&ternary) \h* \) 
                  |  (?&string) 
                  |  (?&parens)  
                )
           )                             # (13 end)

           # p_expression is any parenthesized - function, ternary, or string.
           (?<p_expression>              # (14 start)
                \h* 
                (?:
                     (?&function)  
                  |  (?= . )
                     (?&ternary) 
                  |  (?&string) 
                  |  (?&parens)  
                )
           )                             # (14 end)
      )

 /x';


 function compute($expr) {
     global $rx;
     if (!preg_match($rx, $expr, $m)) {
         return false;
     }

     if ($m['function']) {
         if ($m['parameter']) {
             return $m['func_name'](compute($m['parameter']));
         } else {
             return $m['func_name']( '' );
         }
     }

     if ($m['ternary']) {
         return compute($m['if']) ? compute($m['true']) : compute($m['false']);
     }

     if ($m['parens']) {
         return compute($m['parens_core']);
     }

     return $m['string'];
 }

 function a() {return true; }
 function b() {return false;}
 function d() {return true;}
 function e() {return false;}
 function h() {return true;}
 function intro($p) {if ($p) return 'intro'; return false;}
 function type($p) {if ($p) return 'type'; return false;}
 function insist($p) {if ($p) return 'insist'; return false;}


 $tests = array(
     "a",
     "a()",
     "a(b)",
     "(a?b|c)",
     "(a()?(b()?d|e)|(c()?f|g))",
     "((h() ? a | i) ? (b() ? d | e) | (c() ? f | g))",
     "(a(d(f))?b(e(f))|c)",
     "------------",
     "a?b|c",
     "(a?b|c)",
     " ( ( ( ( ( a ) ) ? ( ( b ) ) | ( ( c ) ) ) ) ) ",
     "b( (oo ? p |u) ) ? x | y",
     "a ?b() | c",
     " a? ( b ? t | r)  | d  ",
     "a()",
     "a? (bhh )   |(c)",
     "(a) ? ((b(oo) ? x | y )) | (c)",
     "a(((b)))",
     "a?    (bhh )   |((c))",
     "(a()?(b()?d|e)|(c()?f|g))",
     "((h() ? a | i) ? (b() ? d | e) | (c() ? f | g))",
     "(((h() ? a | i) ? (b() ? d | e) | (c() ? f | g)))",
     "((h() ? a | i) ? (b() ? d | e) | (c() ? f | g))",
     "(a(d(f))?b(e(f))|c)",
     "------------",
     "((h() ? a | i) ? (b() ? d | e) | (c() ? f | g))",
     "(a(d(f))?b(e(f))|c)",
     '(intro(intro(type(insist(poou))))?toutou|tutu)',
     'type()intro(intro(type(insist(poou))))?type()|tutu'

 );


 foreach ($tests as $test) {
     $result = compute($test);
     echo "$test returns: ";
     var_dump($result);
 }
```

Output:

```
a() returns: bool(true)
a(b) returns: bool(true)
(a?b|c) returns: string(1) "b"
(a()?(b()?d|e)|(c()?f|g)) returns: string(1) "e"
((h() ? a | i) ? (b() ? d | e) | (c() ? f | g)) returns: string(1) "e"
(a(d(f))?b(e(f))|c) returns: bool(false)
------------ returns: bool(false)
a?b|c returns: string(1) "b"
(a?b|c) returns: string(1) "b"
( ( ( ( ( a ) ) ? ( ( b ) ) | ( ( c ) ) ) ) )  returns: string(1) "b"
b( (oo ? p |u) ) ? x | y returns: string(1) "y"
a ?b() | c returns: bool(false)
a? ( b ? t | r)  | d  returns: string(1) "t"
a() returns: bool(true)
a? (bhh )  |(c) returns: string(3) "bhh"
(a) ? ((b(oo) ? x | y )) | (c) returns: bool(false)
a(((b))) returns: bool(true)
a?    (bhh )  |((c)) returns: string(3) "bhh"
(a()?(b()?d|e)|(c()?f|g)) returns: string(1) "e"
((h() ? a | i) ? (b() ? d | e) | (c() ? f | g)) returns: string(1) "e"
(((h() ? a | i) ? (b() ? d | e) | (c() ? f | g))) returns: string(1) "e"
((h() ? a | i) ? (b() ? d | e) | (c() ? f | g)) returns: string(1) "e"
(a(d(f))?b(e(f))|c) returns: bool(false)
------------ returns: bool(false)
((h() ? a | i) ? (b() ? d | e) | (c() ? f | g)) returns: string(1) "e"
(a(d(f))?b(e(f))|c) returns: bool(false)
(intro(intro(type(insist(poou))))?toutou|tutu) returns: string(6) "toutou"
type()intro(intro(type(insist(poou))))?type()|tutu returns: bool(false)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. FYI I've rewritten twice my own Php version, which doesn't use regexp, and it feels just less clear than regexp. Thank you again!

Comment: ...and FYI I've given up on Php because I've discovered Python, rewrote it from scratch, and thanks to that, I've been able to go much further and to finish a very complex "evaluator". **Python: batteries included**