# Regex: re-using a pattern within a group to use in another group

Tags: regex

Hopefully I can explain this properly.

Is it possible to re-use part of my regular to re-use somewhere else within the regex? For example, say you have: `\d{3}` (could be a lot more complex. Made it simple for the purpose of the question) and you want to test this with a combination of either `[a-zA-Z]{3,}` or `[\.a-zA-Z]{10}`. This can be written as  `\d{3}([a-zA-Z]{3,}|[\.a-zA-Z]{10})`. However, if I wish  to use this again, perhaps in the regex, would it be possible or must you re-write this pattern again in order to re-use it. Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Not that I know of. There are back-references that match what an earlier part of the regexp matched, but there's no way to just copy the regexp pattern from earlier. If you're building the regexp in a programming language, you can use its variables for this.

Comment: @Barmar I had a feeling something like this wouldn't exist. I think my worst nightmare is dealing with combinations / permutations of a certain input into my regex. Though storing each pattern in a variable is the only solution in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in whatever programming language you're using to execute the regexp. E.g. in PHP you can do:

```
$subre = '\d{3}([a-zA-Z]{3,}|[\.a-zA-Z]{10})';
if (preg_match("/{$subre}blah{$subre}/", $string)) {
    ...
;
```

Comment: This is the simplest option when it's available, and certainly for things like PHP and JS. Though in some cases it's not possible (for example, an application which provides a search-and-replace dialog with regex capability may not provide a scripting language around it, such as most text editors). This is where the PCRE "define" function comes into play, as noted below.

Answer (score 7):

You can do this if you're using [PCRE](http://www.pcre.org/pcre.txt) (and possibly other regex flavors) by using subpatterns, optionally within a `(DEFINE)` condition.

The examples below are in PHP for demonstration purposes. The definition of `(?<digits>\d{3})` and reference of it with `(?&digits)` is done within the regular expression itself.

---

#### Example:

```
preg_match(
    '/(?<digits>\d{3})([a-zA-Z]{3,}|[\.a-zA-Z]{10})(?&digits)/',
    '123abc456',
    $matches);

var_dump($matches[0]);
```

#### Output:

```
string(9) "123abc456"
```

---

#### Define Example:

```
$regex = <<<'REGEX'
/
(?(DEFINE)
    # A define condition allows you to create subpatterns for use by reference only.
    (?<digits>\d{3})
    (?<letters>[a-zA-Z]{3,}|[\.a-zA-Z]{10})
)
(?&digits)((?&letters))(?&digits)
/x
REGEX;

preg_match($regex, '123abc456', $matches);

var_dump($matches[0]);
```

#### Output:

```
string(9) "123abc456"
```

---

For a more complex example see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27464237/3942918) on creating a syntax parser for a simple grammar.

Comment: I was really looking for an option for it to be done within the pattern itself and not having to use variables in the programming language. But this is an option as well.

Comment: I might have been a little to quick to answer. I'll have to take a look at this in more detail. This might be the best option. I'll get back to you.

Comment: It doesn't affect the validity of the answer, but I think the thing he wants to reuse is the whole `\d{3}([a-zA-Z]{3,}|[\.a-zA-Z]{10})` regexp, not the pieces of it.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but you can accomplish this using pure Regex, using recursion.

Here i name your group as `'name'`, then i simply reused it twice at the end

```
(?'name'\d{3})([a-zA-Z]{3,}|[\.a-zA-Z]{10})\g'name'\g'name'
```